# combobox like IE8 address bar - how to?

Tags: mfc, combobox, autocomplete

i would like to write in MFC combobox that behave like the combo in the IE8 address bar.
with the option of auto complete (which it is a property on the combo - right?) and the delete option on the right
(is the drop down is a list control?)

Answer (score 0):

Check [Using Autocomplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776884%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You can access the edit control in a CComboBoxEx using the GetEditCtrl method.